# Применение метапрограммирования на C++

Tags: метапрограммирование, c++

Сейчас вот читаю книгу Вандервуд и Джосаттис про Шаблоны C++, потом еще Александреску Соверменное проектирование на С++ хочу прочитать. Я читал отзывы в интернете, что эти темы (связанные с метапрограммированием) надо осторожно читать, а какое вообще конкретное применение всему этому есть? Можете сказать? В какие программных проектах часто применяется, какие предметные области? Нужно ли вообще мне всё это, т.е. стоит реально вглдуь ихучать, потому что темы и материал непростые и не сразу всё воспринимается хорошо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Применение - написание различного рода библиотек. Без шаблонов довольно тяжело написать более менее серьёзную библиотеку. В тоже время, метапрограммирование очень удобно применять и в обычных проектах и их грамотное использование в коде, говорит о достаточно хорошей квалификации программиста. Темы конечно не простые, но важные, так как любой уважающий себя программиста на C++, должен это знать. Уверен, что они обязательно вам понадобятся, если вы конечно хотите заниматься программированием профессионально. Александреску конечно классика, но книга уже немного устарела. Хотя это чтение явно лишнем не станет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ну вот я сейчас это читаю:
[Вандервуд Д.Д. — Шаблоны С++. Справочник разработчика](http://lib.mexmat.ru/books/45732). Я как раз профессионально и занимаюсь, но пока джуниор.

Answer (score 2):

Настоятельно рекомендую *(раз есть интерес)* вам ознакомиться с возможностями [**boost::mpl**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) и почитать книгу [**C++ Template Metaprogramming**](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/) от Гуртового и David Abrahams.

*Если хочется капитально загрузить себе мозг, то лучше способа не найти.*

Answer (score -1):

Метапрограммирование на C++ - это извращение. Оно нужно только для того, чтобы обойти дурацкие ограничения языка C++, которые можно было бы очень просто реализовать на уровне языка (типа сравнения типов и static assert'а). Хотя в новом стандарте некоторые ограничения убрали. Шаблоны придумывали, чтобы обобщать типы, а не делать на них программы. Они не были предназначены для метапрограммирования. Ещё оно замедляет скорость компиляции программы.

> Я читал отзывы в интернете, что эти темы (связанные с метапрограммированием) надо осторожно читать

Да уж. Многие употребляют некоторые шаблоны проектирования (например, синглетоны) просто так, даже тогда, когда они не нужны.

Если тебе в самом деле чего-то не хватает для написания программ, можешь посмотреть, а если всё и так получается, лучше метапрограммирование не использовать.

Может быть я и преувеличиваю недостатки, но у меня сложилось такое мнение.
 Вот на языке D метапрограммирование реализовано очень продуманно. Например, чтобы сделать факториал или Фибоначчи во время компиляции, необязательно использовать шаблоны. Обычная функция может выполняться во время компиляции, если она соответствует некоторым условиям.

Comment: Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, минусы, поставленные ответу.

Comment: @GLmonster Извините, влепил сгоряча. Просто, к сожалению, очень положительно отношусь к возможностям метапрограммирования в `C++` и с трудом переношу альтернативные точки зрения. Согласен, что большинство практических задач стоит решать без применения `MP`, поскольку получить красивое и элегантное решение становится в несколько раз сложнее. Тем не менее, несколько раз удавалось очень изящно применять `MP` в продакшене и от этого, видимо, и создалось столь хорошее впечатление. **Минус убрал.**

Comment: > Тем не менее, несколько раз удавалось очень изящно применять MP в продакшене и от этого, видимо, и создалось столь хорошее впечатление.


 Например, что? Может мне пригодится? Я просто ничего полезного для себя не нашёл. Видел только отрицательные стороны.






 Да, я заметил, что поставили и убрали. Кто-то ещё поставил. Интересно, он что скажет?

Comment: @GLmonster Ну один из примеров не очень серьезного `MP` на тему, которая должна быть вам близка - статическая проверка типов параметров, которые передаются шейдеру `Nvidia Cg`. Выложил код для вас [**сюда**][1]. *Есть и более серьезные примеры, но ими уже нужно загружаться полностью)*

[1]: http://pastie.org/2804770

Comment: Посмотрел. Может мне и пригодится, но код с такими шаблонами и макросом выглядит страшновато. Хотя на языке D выглядело бы намного лучше.
 Кстати, сейчас тоже пытаюсь в движок ввести и разобраться с управлением константами. Правда GLSL.